# How to filter 10 values of an array at a time with a delay?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-sheets-api

I have a JSON file with around 400 elements I want to put onto a google sheets. I got that working but I need to keep delay it.

So current code is something like

```
 function workingWithCells(step) {
 sheet.getCells({
     'min-row': 2,
     'max-row': 500,
     'return-empty': true
}, function(err, cells) {
  for (var i = cells.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = parseInt(cells[i].row)
    var tdata = data[row - 2];
```

How would I make it so I would filter 10 rows of the spread sheet and fill in data accordingly, then wait 5 seconds then add another 10 rows of information?

Comment: Try with `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function workingWithCells(){
    sheet.getCells({
}, function(err, cells){
    var doWork = function(i){
        if(cells[i]){
            var row = parseInt(cells[i].row);
            var tdata = data[row - 2];
            setTimeout(function(){
                doWork(i+1);
            }, 1000); // 1 secs delay
        }
    }
    doWork(0);
});
```